# How to run K3s control plane node on AWS and worker nodes on Edge prenmises

Tags: kubernetes, k3s, aws-eks

I would like to know if there is any documentation on how to set up the following k3 cluster architecture

1. Control plane in the AWS
2. Worker nodes on edges premises

Moreover, there is another scenario that I'm looking for where I could set up

1. Control plane + worker nodes (used for training ML)
2. Worker nodes on edge premises (used for serving ML models)

I look forward for  your suggestions.
Best regards,
Florin